I get an error for loading an RSA key when doing version automation using github actions
My main idea is that every time I make a commit it looks to see if the phrase NEW_VERSION:5.0.01 (5.0.01 is just an example in this case) exists somewhere in the commit message and replaces it with a constant with this new version. Here is my code in .yml:
    name: Update Version
    
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - main
    
    jobs:
      update-version:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
          - name: Checkout repository
            uses: actions/checkout@v2
            with:
              fetch-depth: 0
    
          - name: Configure SSH
            run: |
              mkdir -p ~/.ssh
              echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
              chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
              ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
              git config --global user.email "jv0488598@gmail.com"
              git config --global user.name "joaovitorkc"
    
          - name: Start SSH agent
            run: eval `ssh-agent -s`
    
          - name: Install Node.js
            uses: actions/setup-node@v2
            with:
              node-version: '14'
    
          - name: Get last commit message
            id: last_commit
            run: echo "::set-output name=message::$(git log -1 --pretty=%B)"
    
          - name: Extract version from commit message
            id: extract_version
            run: echo "::set-output name=version::$(echo ${{ steps.last_commit.outputs.message }} | grep -oP 'NEW_VERSION:\K\d+\.\d+\.\d+')"
    
          - name: Update version constant in code
            run: |
              if [ -n "${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.version }}" ]; then
                echo "export const VERSION = '${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.version }}';" > src/libs/version.ts
                echo "Version updated to ${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.version }}"
              else
                echo "No new version found in commit message."
              fi
    
          - name: Commit and push updated version
            run: |
              git commit -am "Update version to ${{ steps.extract_version.outputs.version }}"
              git push 

The workflow managed to identify the commit with the message, update the file with the constant, but when it was time to commit, apparently the repository returned that it did not have permissions.
Error details

In order to push a commit during a CI workflow, you need to grant that workflow permission to modify the contents of the repo.
You'll need this:
    jobs:
      update-version:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        permissions:
          contents: write

Now, you also need to make sure you're not trying to push to a protected branch. If this is happening on main and you have rules requiring a PR to update main, those rules will block the push too. However, the error you showed should get fixed by the permissions setting above.
Additional notes

Looking carefully at your logs, I can see that the git commit command worked, it's the git push right after it that generated the error message. That's normal: committing happens in the workflow's sandbox, it's the push that tries to update your repo and needs permission to do it.

The "Configure SSH" and "SSH agent" steps in your workflow won't have any effect, because GitHub Actions always checkout the repo with the HTTPS protocol (as can be seen in the push error message in your log). Actions uses PATs under the hood, and their permissions are controlled by the permissions field. Only the git config calls to set your user name and e-mail have an effect (and you do need those).

For the user name and email, it's more common to use the GH Actions bot address instead of your own, since the commit was made by actions:
git config user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
git config user.email 'github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'

If you use these specific credentials, the commits made by the workflow will have GitHub's Octocat avatar next to them:



